# I can't resize my Oracle VirtualBox virtual machine vmbox screen

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I'm using VM machine by Oracle but the problem is I can't seem to be able to resize the screen.

[image: Image. A screenshot of an Ubuntu virtual machine running in Oracle VirtualBox. The menu item View is selected, with a sub menu open titled Virtual Screen 1. There is an additional sub menu for Virtual Screen 1, with resize options, as well as scaling options]

Answer (score 0):

To resize your Guest Machine, you most likely need to install Virtualbox Extensions in your Guest Machine.

From the screen shot, your Guest machine appears to be Linux and perhaps Ubuntu.

Here is a tutorial to install Guest Extensions for Ubuntu.

[Ubuntu Guest Extensions](https://linuxconfig.org/virtualbox-extension-pack-installation-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux)

.

> Open terminal window and use the following apt command to install the
> VirtualBox Extension Pack:
>
> $ sudo apt install virtualbox-ext-pack

.

Restart the Guest machine after installing the extension pack.